Stack Exchange should allow existing users to opt out of arbitration
Please allow users to opt out of arbitration, even if it's more than the 30 days since they signed the agreement.
Currently the terms of service read:

PLEASE BE AWARE THAT BY USING THE PUBLIC NETWORK, EXCEPT FOR CERTAIN TYPES OF DISPUTES DESCRIBED IN THE SECTION TITLED “MANDATORY ARBITRATION” BELOW, YOU AGREE THAT ALL DISPUTES BETWEEN YOU AND US WILL BE RESOLVED BY BINDING, INDIVIDUAL ARBITRATION AND YOU WAIVE YOUR RIGHT TO PARTICIPATE IN A CLASS ACTION LAWSUIT OR CLASS-WIDE ARBITRATION.
[...]
If you don’t want to be bound by the arbitration and class-action waiver provisions in this section, you must notify us in writing within thirty (30) days of the date that you first accept these Public Network Terms (unless a longer period is required by applicable law), and then you must litigate any disputes against us in accordance with the “Assignment and Jurisdiction” section below.

Not only has Disney attempted to use Arbitration for a wrongful death case until the backlash became too severe, but now Uber is trying to do that with crash victims.
I didn't know that companies would be so evil in their use of arbitration, but I do know now.
I've tried privately requesting that I want to opt out of arbitration, back in August, but apart from an email saying they'd probably respond in a few days, I didn't get anything, even though I tried following up.

If you're going to make a post like this, I would really appreciate if you would cite a better source than a YouTube short.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution No, that's not how it works. When you agree to the terms, it's you as a person who is agreeing, not your account.

@joojaa Your choice. That also stops arbitration for all future contributions, if there are none. But if you want to continue posting without arbitration and the company is not forthcoming a bit of de- and re-registration would be necessary.

Based on your profile you live in Australia. IF you are lucky enough, your country may not even recognize Stack arbitration clause as legal in the first place - you may want to look into this. Past that, I agree the whole arbitration thing is pretty horrible, especially when you place it in the "Monica" timeframe.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution The point here is that there now is jurisprudence (the Uber case) that this arbitration applies even if the dispute is entirely unrelated to the reason this arbitration clause was agreed on. So if, 10 years down the line, SE AI gunbots decide to shoot your dog, arbitration can still be enforced, even if you deleted your account and haven't contributed in a decade.

Forced arbitration needs to be squashed on a much broader level than just at Stack/ company by company, but that's neither here nor there. Any company being able to broadly opt-out of legal accountability with such a tiny, flippant clause in their ToS is outrageous.

Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/82736
